# How to solve this inequality? $\sqrt x\geqslant x-6.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How to solve this inequality? $$\sqrt x\geqslant x-6.$$

My answer is $[4,9]$, but it must be $[0,9]$, I don't understand what's wrong. Could you give me solution?

Comment: Can you write what you did? Its better because we can help you to fix the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems you squared it to get $x \ge (x-6)^2$, which you solved correctly.  The squaring covered up the solutions for $x \in [0,4)$.  You should work to understand why-it is important.

Answer (score 1):

$x-\sqrt{x}-6=(\sqrt{x}-3)(\sqrt{x}+2)$ but not $(\sqrt{x}-3)(\sqrt{x}-2)$.
$$\sqrt{x}\geq x-6\Leftrightarrow x-\sqrt{x}-6=(\sqrt{x}-3)(\sqrt{x}+2)\leq0\Leftrightarrow-2\leq\sqrt{x}\leq3\Leftrightarrow0\leq x\leq9$$

Answer (score 0):

First condition - $x \ge 0$. Now, we can write that the inequality holds for $x \le 6$, because LHS is non-negative and RHS is non-positive.

If $x>6$ we can square both sided and get $x \ge (x-6)^2 \rightarrow x\ge x^2-12x+36 \rightarrow 0 \ge x^2-13x+36$.

We will get $x\in[4,9]$, but we checked that for $x>6$, thus $x\in(6,9]$. We also find that the inequality holds for $x\in[0,6]$.

Finally we get that the inequality holds for $x\in[0,9]$.

Answer (score 0):

From $a \ge b$, you can't deduce $a^2 \ge b^2$. That is only valid if $a \ge 0$ and $b \ge 0$. (Try $a=1$ and $b=-2$ for a counterexample.)